# How to store in a List only those Types that are inherited from a certain class?

Tags: c#

I want to make a list of allowed to create magic by my player, and I want to protect the list from accidentally writing an object there that is not inherited from the Magic class.

```
class Magic
{
...
}
class FireBall: Magic
class IceBall: Magic

class Player
{
    List<...> magicAllowedForSpawning;
}
```

Comment: While you can use constraints, this would only be interesting if you wanted to have several lists, but all containing types stemming from the same base class. Your case (a single list of magic), iiuc, is much simpler though: Because C# deals only with references, you can not only store references to T in a List<T> but automatically references to all base classes as well. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/polymorphism for an example.

Comment: @Steve why are you advocating inheriting List for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply `List<Magic>` and add the childs here, but then you only can use base props, if you  want to use specific property you  must cast this item to specific class that you  want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

why not simply use List ?. you can add both Fireball and Iceball objects to List of Magic class.

```
class Magic
{
}
class FireBall: Magic
{}
class IceBall: Magic
{}

class Player
{
     public List<Magic> magicAllowedForSpawning;
     public List<FireBall> GetFireballs()
     {
         var fireBalls = magicAllowedForSpawning.Where((a) => a.GetType() == typeof(FireBall)).Select(x=> (FireBall)x).ToList();



         return fireBalls;


     }

     public void AddFireball(FireBall b){
     
         magicAllowedForSpawning.Add(b);
     }
     public void AddIceball(IceBall b){
     
         magicAllowedForSpawning.Add(b);
     }
}
```